# How to link a favorite button to a new activity?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails-3, android-layout, button

I want to add a favorite button in a layout which can save the layout and apply it to another activity. I'll show you an image bellow to understand exactly the way I want to do it..

[image: How i would like it to look]

I created the favorite button, and the activity for this button to save the layout, but the app is still crashing when I press the favorite button and the activity which should open the layout, which I have saved, is blank. Here are the code:

```
public void onClick(View v){    
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      prefs.edit().putString("activity", "YourActivityName");
}

public void onClick(View v){
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
          getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String activityToRun = prefs.getString("activity", "noFavorites"); 
    if(activityToRun.equals("noFavorites")
      return null;
    if(activityToRun.equals("YOUR FIRST ACTIVTY")
     //code for launching activity
}
```

I added this to `Favorite.java`, and I created another activity, called `Favorite2.java` which should be open the layout saved by the favorite button, but what I don't understand is how I can link the saved layout to the activity `Favorite2.java`?

And please, if someone can tell me exactly the explanation for getString and putString and the way that they should be implemented.

Comment: can you post link to blog so we get complete idea about the code and problem you are facing

Comment: I think this is what you need to know.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430299/how-to-create-this-favorite-button-in-an-android-app/21431083?noredirect=1#comment32336595_21431083

Comment: Do you want more information? Can you help me please..?